# Clean Code - Are output parameters bad?

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I was looking at a former colleagues post. He quoted something from an [article](http://paytonrules.com/software-development/2014/10/03/output-arguments.html)

> "In Clean Code Bob Martin disparages output arguments, saying “In general output arguments should be avoided.”

My current code base is C#. I am working in a rather large application. It was written primarily in procedural style often breaking SOLID principles. When I have the opportunity I often will break some of the methods that violate single responsibility principle into separate methods. At times I'll create methods with a couple of output parameters as in the following.

```
var value1 int;
var value2 int;

DoSomeWork(out value1, out value2);
```

I prefer this over creating a special types which would never be reused anyways if a type were created. Is this acceptable or is there a better approach?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better question for [programmers.se]? (I bet it's already on there)

Comment: This is OT for StackOverflow. I'll say this: anything that gives you a blanket statement of "don't use X" without an explanation of why or what the alternatives are should be ignored. Secondly, every style rule has exceptions. If you're using output parameters all the time with the same parameters reused, then you really should have an object with methods that operate on its internal data. If you are doing, say, a conversion routine that could fail, output parameters are fine.

Comment: If you don't want to create a new type you could return a `Tuple<int, int>`.

Comment: Similar question on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/322490/what-is-an-output-argument-as-refered-to-in-martins-clean-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct that output parameters should generally be avoided. When possible (and reasonable) it's better to just return the result. Using output variables gives you a process of Prepare - Call - Handle that is more complex than it has to be.

You don't always have to create a new type to use for return value. There are types in the framework that you can use as long as you don't need a specific name for the components in the return value:

```
public Tuple<int, int> CalculateMinMax()
```

This is of couse only good if the meaning of the return value is obvious. In the example above the two values would be expected to be the minimum and maximum that was calculated, in that order.

If the return value is more complex, you are better off creating a type for it. If it's that complex, then using output variables for it will not make for simple code either.

**Update**

In more recent versions of C#, you can use tuple types to return a tuple with named properties. For example:

```
public (int Min, int Max) CalculateMinMax()
```

There are several ways to handle the result. You can get the result as a tuple:

```
(int Min, int Max) limits = CalculateMinMax();
```

You can populate existing variables:

```
(min, max) = CalculateMinMax();
```

You can declare new variables:

```
(int min, int max) = CalculateMinMax();
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I've never used Tuple. This syntax would fit my situation 90% of the time. I have to agree also that if the values returned involved more complicated/involved calculation that a strong type should be used. 
Yell out to Lee as well, thank you both

Answer (score 4):

**TL:DR; If you're writing high level code, you shouldn't use output parameters.**

There are good reasons to use output parameters in some cases. For example, `int.TryParse` is a perfect example of a function which uses output parameters to return a second value.

One could argue that the reason for that is efficiency, since it doesn't need to construct a wrapper object just to parse an integer.

On the other hand, if you write high level code, you should probably use a class or a struct that wraps those two values. If all you're doing is returning two values, you can use `Tuple` or write your own `struct` that will have almost no overhead. I'm saying almost no overhead, since all object creation will have *some overhead*.

If you're writing a tight loop that needs to run as fast as possible, for example a parser of some sort, you might benefit more from using the output parameters, which won't have to allocate any excessive objects.