# Returnvalue with ref compared to two out Values

Tags: c#

I had a discussion with a collegue today, about how its best to return two values.
We had three differing opinions. Important to the problem is, that we can't use an extra class or struct(therefore no Tuple) which was the prefered answer in this question: [Clean Code - Are output parameters bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204827/clean-code-are-output-parameters-bad) .

```
public enum Offset
{
    None = 0,
    Training = 10,
    Cancel = 20
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Option 1
    int outValue = 0;
    Offset outOffset;
    HandleOffset(35, out outValue, out outOffset);

    //Option 2
    int refValue = 0;
    outOffset = SubtractOffset(ref refValue);

    //Option 3
    outOffset = GetOffsetById(35);
    int id = GetIdWithoutOffset(35);
}

//Option 1
public static void HandleOffset(int inValue, out int outValue, out Offset outOffset)
{
    outValue = inValue;
    outOffset = Offset.None;
    if ((inValue-(int)Offset.Cancel)>15)
    {
        outValue -= (int)Offset.Cancel;
        outOffset |= Offset.Cancel;
    }
    if ((inValue - (int)Offset.Training) > 15)
    {
        outValue -= (int)Offset.Training;
        outOffset |= Offset.Training;
    }
}

//Option 2
public static Offset SubtractOffset(ref int id)
{
    Offset offset = Offset.None;
    if ((id - (int)Offset.Cancel) > 15)
    {
        id -= (int)Offset.Cancel;
        offset |= Offset.Cancel;
    }
    if ((id - (int)Offset.Training) > 15)
    {
        id -= (int)Offset.Training;
        offset |= Offset.Training;
    }
    return offset;
}

//Option 3
public static Offset GetOffsetById(int id)
{
    Offset offset = Offset.None;
    if ((id - (int)Offset.Cancel) > 15)
    {
        offset |= Offset.Cancel;
    }
    if ((id - (int)Offset.Training) > 15)
    {
        offset |= Offset.Training;
    }
    return offset;
}

//Option 3
public static int GetIdWithoutOffset(int id)
{
    if ((id - (int)Offset.Cancel) > 15)
    {
        id -= (int)Offset.Cancel;
    }
    if ((id - (int)Offset.Training) > 15)
    {
        id -= (int)Offset.Training;
    }
    return id;
}
```

Option 2 seems ugly because of the return value + ref value.

Option 1 seems to be also ugly because of the two output parameters but in fact it looks cleaner than the second option.

Option 3 looks the cleanest to me.

Which of those solutions is regarded the cleanest solution( clean as in clean code by bob martin ), or is there another option to solve the problem, which we might not have thought of ?

Comment: What's the performance difference? I can understand the desire for ref/out if there is a major speedup for performance critical code, but I think if you're looking for clean as in "clean code by bob martin" that option 3 is the closest. Generally, people at my company tend to avoid ref/out parameters because it is an indicator that your method is trying to do too much.

Comment: Option 4: 2 functions each of which just `return`s

Comment: @zerkms could you explain your solution ? whats the difference to the option 3 ?

Comment: Are you seriously comparing the speed of passing parameters in functions by 'ref', 'out' and 'return' parameters? That has never been the point as far as I understood from 'bob martin' or any other performance purist like 'Jeffrey Richter'. If your system was really that performance critical you could argue that passing large value types (struct > 32B) would perform faster by 'ref' than by value (without 'ref').

Comment: May I ask, why you can't use extra class/struct? This is how I think: 1. Is performance critical? 2. Is your function cohesive (i.e. doing too many things in the same function). Based on that, if performance is critical, go with the fastest solution. Else, if function is cohesive, go with an appropriate compound return type (class/struct/array, etc), else split function into multiple cohesive functions.

Comment: @MartinLottering right, that has never been the point, I was just stating that it is the fastest, to give you some indication what the discussion was all about in the first place. Now i am only interested in clean code principles

Comment: If you are only interested in "clean" code, then your question should include less "which is fastest" or "that is slower" comments. Seriously, there is no direct correlation that makes sense. Especially when comparing at the level of method parameters, which is irrelevant for most software projects. Unless yours is very performance critical. My colleague didn't believe me when I told him that string.ToUpper is faster than string.ToLower, especially for performance critical projects, but it is true for .net projects like ours.It helps to know these things when performance is the primary goal.

Comment: @MartinLottering maybe you are right. I removed the "THIS is fastest" which isn't exactly "which is fastest" like you said. Nevertehless it seems to have cluttered the question

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the most clean solution is the one not requiring any `out` or `ref`-parameters (best is a struct/class, tuples also work). Since you are not allowed to use classes/structs or tuples, which would be the preferred way, I'd still use the first option for being the easiest.

The second option, in my opinion, is complete bullshit, because the `out`-keyword is supposed to do exactly what you want, so using `ref` is not at all necessary.

The third option is okay, although very cluttered and not that easy. Since you cannot use tuples and want to maintain a clear code, avoid it.

TL;DR: Use the first option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to throw this out there, though I would never do this in production (at least for a public API).

An alternative option is to use a [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) return type. No out param. No ref param. Only an obfuscation of the values being returned:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic offset = HandleOffset();

        Console.WriteLine(offset);
    }

    public static dynamic HandleOffset()
    {
        return new
        {
            Value = 64, 
            Offset = Offset.Cancel
        };
    }
}

public enum Offset
{
    None = 0,
    Training = 10,
    Cancel = 20
}
```

Comment: Wow this is interesting. I agree that i wouldn't want to use it in production if I have different options but this is really interesting. +1